# mysql select two prior to and one after NOW()

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with a column `event_time`. How can I select two rows right before NOW() and the next one after NOW(), ordered by `event_time`?

Is is possible with a single query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT *
FROM    (
            SELECT *
            FROM TABLE
            WHERE event_time < NOW()
            ORDER BY event_time DESC
            LIMIT 2
        ) First2
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM    (
            SELECT *
            FROM TABLE
            WHERE event_time > NOW()
            ORDER BY event_time ASC
            LIMIT 1
        ) Next1
ORDER BY event_time
```